# Keycloak redirecting to IDP login after authentication over HTTPS

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api, keycloak-connect

**Environment:**

- Keycloak version: 20.0.2

**Problem:**

- Application (SP) running on port 8080.
- Keycloak (IDP) running on port 8443.
- HTTP authentication works correctly.
- HTTPS authentication redirects to https://localhost:8443/login instead of https://localhost:8080/login after Keycloak authentication.

**Configurations:**

```
{
“clientId”: “",
“name”: "",
“description”: “”,
“rootUrl”: “https://localhost:8080”,
“adminUrl”: “”,
“baseUrl”: “”,
“surrogateAuthRequired”: false,
“enabled”: true,
“alwaysDisplayInConsole”: false,
“clientAuthenticatorType”: “client-secret”,
“redirectUris”: [
"/saml/”
],
“webOrigins”: ,
“notBefore”: 0,
“bearerOnly”: false,
“consentRequired”: false,
“standardFlowEnabled”: true,
“implicitFlowEnabled”: false,
“directAccessGrantsEnabled”: true,
“serviceAccountsEnabled”: false,
“publicClient”: true,
“frontchannelLogout”: true,
“protocol”: “saml”,
“attributes”: {
“saml.assertion.signature”: “true”,
“saml.force.post.binding”: “true”,
“saml_single_logout_service_url_post”: “/saml/logout”,
“saml.encrypt”: “false”,
“saml_assertion_consumer_url_post”: “/saml/SSO”,
“saml.server.signature”: “true”,
“saml.server.signature.keyinfo.ext”: “false”,
“saml.signing.certificate”: “hidden”,
“saml.artifact.binding.identifier”: “hidden”,
“saml.artifact.binding”: “false”,
“saml.signature.algorithm”: “RSA_SHA256”,
“saml_force_name_id_format”: “false”,
“saml.server.signature.keyinfo$xmlSigKeyInfoKeyNameTransformer”: “KEY_ID”,
“saml.client.signature”: “false”,
“saml.force.name.id.format”: “false”,
“saml.authnstatement”: “true”,
“display.on.consent.screen”: “false”,
“saml_name_id_format”: “email”,
“saml.signing.private.key”: “hidden”,
“saml.allow.ecp.flow”: “false”,
“saml_signature_canonicalization_method”: “Exclusive XML Canonicalization Version 1.0”,
“saml.onetimeuse.condition”: “false”
},
“authenticationFlowBindingOverrides”: {},
“fullScopeAllowed”: true,
“nodeReRegistrationTimeout”: -1,
“defaultClientScopes”: [
“role_list”
],
“optionalClientScopes”: ,
“access”: {
“view”: true,
“configure”: true,
“manage”: true
}
}
```

[image: IDP Config 1]
[image: IDP Config 2]

**

Code Context:WEB SECURITY CONFIG**

Relevant code:websecurity configs

```
/*
* Copyright 2019 Vincenzo De Notaris
*
* Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
* you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
* You may obtain a copy of the License at
*
*     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
*
* Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
* distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
* WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
* See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
* limitations under the License. 
*/

package com.vdenotaris.spring.boot.security.saml.web.config;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Timer;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager;
import org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine;
import org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider;
import org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProvider;
import org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException;
import org.opensaml.xml.parse.ParserPool;
import org.opensaml.xml.parse.StaticBasicParserPool;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.core.io.DefaultResourceLoader;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLBootstrap;
import org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLDiscovery;
import org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutFilter;
import org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter;
import org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter;
import org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter;
import org.springframework.security.saml.context.SAMLContextProviderImpl;
import org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager;
import org.springframework.security.saml.key.KeyManager;
import org.springframework.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger;
import org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager;
import org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata;
import org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate;
import org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataDisplayFilter;
import org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator;
import org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter;
import org.springframework.security.saml.parser.ParserPoolHolder;
import org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPArtifactBinding;
import org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPPAOS11Binding;
import org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPPostBinding;
import org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding;
import org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPSOAP11Binding;
import org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLBinding;
import org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl;
import org.springframework.security.saml.trust.httpclient.TLSProtocolConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.saml.util.VelocityFactory;
import org.springframework.security.saml.websso.ArtifactResolutionProfile;
import org.springframework.security.saml.websso.ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl;
import org.springframework.security.saml.websso.SingleLogoutProfile;
import org.springframework.security.saml.websso.SingleLogoutProfileImpl;
import org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfile;
import org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumer;
import org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl;
import org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl;
import org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileECPImpl;
import org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileImpl;
import org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileOptions;
import org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

import com.vdenotaris.spring.boot.security.saml.web.core.SAMLUserDetailsServiceImpl;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements InitializingBean, DisposableBean {

    private Timer backgroundTaskTimer;
    private MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager;

    public void init() {
        this.backgroundTaskTimer = new Timer(true);
        this.multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager = new MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager();
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        this.backgroundTaskTimer.purge();
        this.backgroundTaskTimer.cancel();
        this.multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.shutdown();
    }
    
    @Autowired
    private SAMLUserDetailsServiceImpl samlUserDetailsServiceImpl;
    
    // Initialization of the velocity engine
    @Bean
    public VelocityEngine velocityEngine() {
        return VelocityFactory.getEngine();
    }

    // XML parser pool needed for OpenSAML parsing
    @Bean(initMethod = "initialize")
    public StaticBasicParserPool parserPool() {
        return new StaticBasicParserPool();
    }

    @Bean(name = "parserPoolHolder")
    public ParserPoolHolder parserPoolHolder() {
        return new ParserPoolHolder();
    }

    // Bindings, encoders and decoders used for creating and parsing messages
    @Bean
    public HttpClient httpClient() {
        return new HttpClient(this.multiThreadedHttpConnectionManager);
    }

    // SAML Authentication Provider responsible for validating of received SAML
    // messages
    @Bean
    public SAMLAuthenticationProvider samlAuthenticationProvider() {
        SAMLAuthenticationProvider samlAuthenticationProvider = new SAMLAuthenticationProvider();
        samlAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetails(samlUserDetailsServiceImpl);
        samlAuthenticationProvider.setForcePrincipalAsString(false);
        return samlAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    // Provider of default SAML Context
    @Bean
    public SAMLContextProviderImpl contextProvider() {
        return new SAMLContextProviderImpl();
    }

    // Initialization of OpenSAML library
    @Bean
    public static SAMLBootstrap sAMLBootstrap() {
        return new SAMLBootstrap();
    }

    // Logger for SAML messages and events
    @Bean
    public SAMLDefaultLogger samlLogger() {
        return new SAMLDefaultLogger();
    }

    // SAML 2.0 WebSSO Assertion Consumer
    @Bean
    public WebSSOProfileConsumer webSSOprofileConsumer() {
        return new WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl();
    }

    // SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key WebSSO Assertion Consumer
    @Bean
    public WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl hokWebSSOprofileConsumer() {
        return new WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl();
    }

    // SAML 2.0 Web SSO profile
    @Bean
    public WebSSOProfile webSSOprofile() {
        return new WebSSOProfileImpl();
    }

    // SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key Web SSO profile
    @Bean
    public WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl hokWebSSOProfile() {
        return new WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl();
    }

    // SAML 2.0 ECP profile
    @Bean
    public WebSSOProfileECPImpl ecpprofile() {
        return new WebSSOProfileECPImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public SingleLogoutProfile logoutprofile() {
        return new SingleLogoutProfileImpl();
    }

    // Central storage of cryptographic keys
    @Bean
    public KeyManager keyManager() {
        DefaultResourceLoader loader = new DefaultResourceLoader();
        Resource storeFile = loader
                .getResource("classpath:/saml/samlKeystore.jks");
        String storePass = "nalle123";
        Map<String, String> passwords = new HashMap<String, String>();
        passwords.put("apollo", "nalle123");
        String defaultKey = "apollo";
        return new JKSKeyManager(storeFile, storePass, passwords, defaultKey);
    }

    // Setup TLS Socket Factory
    @Bean
    public TLSProtocolConfigurer tlsProtocolConfigurer() {
        return new TLSProtocolConfigurer();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public WebSSOProfileOptions defaultWebSSOProfileOptions() {
        WebSSOProfileOptions webSSOProfileOptions = new WebSSOProfileOptions();
        webSSOProfileOptions.setIncludeScoping(false);
        return webSSOProfileOptions;
    }

    // Entry point to initialize authentication, default values taken from
    // properties file
    @Bean
    public SAMLEntryPoint samlEntryPoint() {
        SAMLEntryPoint samlEntryPoint = new SAMLEntryPoint();
        samlEntryPoint.setDefaultProfileOptions(defaultWebSSOProfileOptions());
        return samlEntryPoint;
    }
    
    // Setup advanced info about metadata
    @Bean
    public ExtendedMetadata extendedMetadata() {
            ExtendedMetadata extendedMetadata = new ExtendedMetadata();
            extendedMetadata.setIdpDiscoveryEnabled(true); 
            extendedMetadata.setSignMetadata(false);
            extendedMetadata.setEcpEnabled(true);
            return extendedMetadata;
    }
    
    // IDP Discovery Service
    @Bean
    public SAMLDiscovery samlIDPDiscovery() {
        SAMLDiscovery idpDiscovery = new SAMLDiscovery();
        idpDiscovery.setIdpSelectionPath("/saml/discovery");
        return idpDiscovery;
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("idp-ssocircle")
    public ExtendedMetadataDelegate ssoCircleExtendedMetadataProvider()
            throws MetadataProviderException {
        String idpSSOCircleMetadataURL = "https://idp.ssocircle.com/idp-meta.xml";
        HTTPMetadataProvider httpMetadataProvider = new HTTPMetadataProvider(
                this.backgroundTaskTimer, httpClient(), idpSSOCircleMetadataURL);
        httpMetadataProvider.setParserPool(parserPool());
        ExtendedMetadataDelegate extendedMetadataDelegate = 
                new ExtendedMetadataDelegate(httpMetadataProvider, extendedMetadata());
        extendedMetadataDelegate.setMetadataTrustCheck(true);
        extendedMetadataDelegate.setMetadataRequireSignature(false);
        backgroundTaskTimer.purge();
        return extendedMetadataDelegate;
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("idp-keycloak")
    public ExtendedMetadataDelegate keycloakExtendedMetadataProvider(Environment env)
            throws MetadataProviderException {
        String idpKeycloakMetadataURL = env.getRequiredProperty("keycloak.auth-server-url") + "/protocol/saml/descriptor";
        HTTPMetadataProvider httpMetadataProvider = new HTTPMetadataProvider(
                this.backgroundTaskTimer, httpClient(), idpKeycloakMetadataURL);
        httpMetadataProvider.setParserPool(parserPool());
        ExtendedMetadataDelegate extendedMetadataDelegate =
                new ExtendedMetadataDelegate(httpMetadataProvider, extendedMetadata());
        extendedMetadataDelegate.setMetadataTrustCheck(true);
        extendedMetadataDelegate.setMetadataRequireSignature(false);
        backgroundTaskTimer.purge();
        return extendedMetadataDelegate;
    }

    // IDP Metadata configuration - paths to metadata of IDPs in circle of trust
    // is here
    // Do no forget to call iniitalize method on providers
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("metadata")
    public CachingMetadataManager metadata(List<MetadataProvider> providers) throws MetadataProviderException {
        return new CachingMetadataManager(providers);
    }

    // Filter automatically generates default SP metadata
    @Bean
    public MetadataGenerator metadataGenerator() {
        MetadataGenerator metadataGenerator = new MetadataGenerator();
        metadataGenerator.setEntityId("com:vdenotaris:spring:sp");
        metadataGenerator.setExtendedMetadata(extendedMetadata());
        metadataGenerator.setIncludeDiscoveryExtension(false);
        metadataGenerator.setKeyManager(keyManager()); 
        return metadataGenerator;
    }

    // The filter is waiting for connections on URL suffixed with filterSuffix
    // and presents SP metadata there
    @Bean
    public MetadataDisplayFilter metadataDisplayFilter() {
        return new MetadataDisplayFilter();
    }
    
    // Handler deciding where to redirect user after successful login
    @Bean
    public SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successRedirectHandler() {
        SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successRedirectHandler =
                new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        successRedirectHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl("/landing");
        return successRedirectHandler;
    }
    
    // Handler deciding where to redirect user after failed login
    @Bean
    public SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler() {
            SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler =
                    new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler();
            failureHandler.setUseForward(true);
            failureHandler.setDefaultFailureUrl("/error");
            return failureHandler;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
        SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter = new SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter();
        samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successRedirectHandler());
        samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler());
        return samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter;
    }
    
    // Processing filter for WebSSO profile messages
    @Bean
    public SAMLProcessingFilter samlWebSSOProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
        SAMLProcessingFilter samlWebSSOProcessingFilter = new SAMLProcessingFilter();
        samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successRedirectHandler());
        samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler());
        return samlWebSSOProcessingFilter;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public MetadataGeneratorFilter metadataGeneratorFilter() {
        return new MetadataGeneratorFilter(metadataGenerator());
    }
    
    // Handler for successful logout
    @Bean
    public SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler successLogoutHandler() {
        SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler successLogoutHandler = new SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler();
        successLogoutHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl("/");
        return successLogoutHandler;
    }
    
    // Logout handler terminating local session
    @Bean
    public SecurityContextLogoutHandler logoutHandler() {
        SecurityContextLogoutHandler logoutHandler = 
                new SecurityContextLogoutHandler();
        logoutHandler.setInvalidateHttpSession(true);
        logoutHandler.setClearAuthentication(true);
        return logoutHandler;
    }

    // Filter processing incoming logout messages
    // First argument determines URL user will be redirected to after successful
    // global logout
    @Bean
    public SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter samlLogoutProcessingFilter() {
        return new SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter(successLogoutHandler(),
                logoutHandler());
    }
    
    // Overrides default logout processing filter with the one processing SAML
    // messages
    @Bean
    public SAMLLogoutFilter samlLogoutFilter() {
        return new SAMLLogoutFilter(successLogoutHandler(),
                new LogoutHandler[] { logoutHandler() },
                new LogoutHandler[] { logoutHandler() });
    }
    
    // Bindings
    private ArtifactResolutionProfile artifactResolutionProfile() {
        final ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl artifactResolutionProfile = 
                new ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl(httpClient());
        artifactResolutionProfile.setProcessor(new SAMLProcessorImpl(soapBinding()));
        return artifactResolutionProfile;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public HTTPArtifactBinding artifactBinding(ParserPool parserPool, VelocityEngine velocityEngine) {
        return new HTTPArtifactBinding(parserPool, velocityEngine, artifactResolutionProfile());
    }

    @Bean
    public HTTPSOAP11Binding soapBinding() {
        return new HTTPSOAP11Binding(parserPool());
    }
    
    @Bean
    public HTTPPostBinding httpPostBinding() {
            return new HTTPPostBinding(parserPool(), velocityEngine());
    }
    
    @Bean
    public HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding httpRedirectDeflateBinding() {
            return new HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding(parserPool());
    }
    
    @Bean
    public HTTPSOAP11Binding httpSOAP11Binding() {
        return new HTTPSOAP11Binding(parserPool());
    }
    
    @Bean
    public HTTPPAOS11Binding httpPAOS11Binding() {
            return new HTTPPAOS11Binding(parserPool());
    }
    
    // Processor
    @Bean
    public SAMLProcessorImpl processor() {
        Collection<SAMLBinding> bindings = new ArrayList<SAMLBinding>();
        bindings.add(httpRedirectDeflateBinding());
        bindings.add(httpPostBinding());
        bindings.add(artifactBinding(parserPool(), velocityEngine()));
        bindings.add(httpSOAP11Binding());
        bindings.add(httpPAOS11Binding());
        return new SAMLProcessorImpl(bindings);
    }
    
    /**
    * Define the security filter chain in order to support SSO Auth by using SAML 2.0
    * 
    * @return Filter chain proxy
    * @throws Exception
    */
    @Bean
    public FilterChainProxy samlFilter() throws Exception {
        List<SecurityFilterChain> chains = new ArrayList<SecurityFilterChain>();
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/login/**"),
                samlEntryPoint()));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/logout/**"),
                samlLogoutFilter()));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/metadata/**"),
                metadataDisplayFilter()));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/SSO/**"),
                samlWebSSOProcessingFilter()));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/SSOHoK/**"),
                samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter()));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/SingleLogout/**"),
                samlLogoutProcessingFilter()));
        chains.add(new DefaultSecurityFilterChain(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/saml/discovery/**"),
                samlIDPDiscovery()));
        return new FilterChainProxy(chains);
    }
    
    /**
    * Returns the authentication manager currently used by Spring.
    * It represents a bean definition with the aim allow wiring from
    * other classes performing the Inversion of Control (IoC).
    * 
    * @throws  Exception 
    */
    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
    
    /**
    * Defines the web based security configuration.
    * 
    * @param   http It allows configuring web based security for specific http requests.
    * @throws  Exception 
    */
    @Override  
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .httpBasic()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(samlEntryPoint());      
        http
                .addFilterBefore(metadataGeneratorFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
                .addFilterAfter(samlFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(samlFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
        http        
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/saml/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/img/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/js/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
        http
                .logout()
                    .disable(); // The logout procedure is already handled by SAML filters.
    }

    /**
    * Sets a custom authentication provider.
    * 
    * @param   auth SecurityBuilder used to create an AuthenticationManager.
    * @throws  Exception 
    */
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .authenticationProvider(samlAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        init();
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() throws Exception {
        shutdown();
    }

}
```

**Attempted Solutions:**

- Modified valid redirect URLs and relay state in Keycloak configuration.

**Request for Assistance:**

- Seeking guidance to resolve the HTTPS redirection issue.

**Thank you in advance for your assistance!**

Comment: Please include your code snippets in your question inline. External links will disappear in the future.

Comment: can you please help on this . I added that code snippet. @Manuel

Comment: Add DEBUG log. Show us the authentication URL your SP generated for HTTP and HTTPs. Show us the generated Keycloak events.